# Client continually hitting Max Children Limits on PHP

Tags: configuration, php-5.4, apache

I have a client who is with an un-named hosting company on a shared server. They are continually hitting a Max Children Limit on their PHP which causes their site to crash.

Is there away in Apache to clean these up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Apache, not about magento itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child limit is being hit because they are all busy. It isn't a case of a child being used to load a page, then it sits in use until a timeout is hit. The child is unavailable because it is in use.

Looking at the output of `top` can be telling in this respect.

- If the processes are sat with near 100% CPU, you can assume they are doing something and that restarting Apache or killing these children is only going to stop what it was doing. That could mean killing a customer page load, admin activity etc.
- If the processes are sat with 0% CPU, then they could be waiting on another service or that the child is satisfying a large static request. MySQL is the likely cause at this point, review with `mytop` and see if there are any queued queries.

In either case, the solution is to never kill the process, but understand why it is busy.

In the examples above, for the former, you clearly need to up the child limit (CPU willing, 2 children per CPU is a good balance). For the latter, reviewing the cause of the secondary bottleneck is wise.

A few minutes diagnosis will tell you what to do next.